# Different approaches of defining tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) Wikipedia article says that tensors can be defined as miltilinear maps or be defined using tensor products. Could anybody explain with a simple example why these two approaches give the same objects?

---

[**Added**:] In *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote, we have the following theorem, 
[image]

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and consider $L=\mathbb{R}$, $M_1=V$, $M_2=V^*$. Then every multilinear map $\varphi:V^*\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ is corresponding to a homomorphism $\Phi: V^*\otimes V\to\mathbb{R}$. According to one of the approaches in the linked Wikipedia article, $\varphi$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor. On the other hand, an element of the tensor product $V^*\otimes V$ is also called a tensor. Does $\varphi$ also corresponds to an element of $V^*\otimes V$? Does one need to identify $V^*\otimes V$ with its dual to have such correspondence?

Answer (score 1):

For example taking two linear maps $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ one can construct a bilinear map $f\otimes g:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ via
$$f\otimes g(v,w)=f(v)g(w).$$
Attached to $f\otimes g$ there is a matrix associated by evaluating 
$$f\otimes g(b_i,b_j),$$
that is
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
f(b_1)g(b_1)&f(b_1)g(b_2)&...&f(b_1)g(b_n)\\
f(b_2)g(b_1)&f(b_2)g(b_2)&...&f(b_2)g(b_n)\\
\\
f(b_n)g(b_1)&f(b_n)g(b_2)&...&f(b_n)g(b_n)\\
\end{array}\right),$$ 
and where the $\{b_i\}$ are basis vectors for $\Bbb R^n$.

An important consequence is the alternating bilinear maps or a.k.a. bi-vectors, 2-vectors, 2-forms... are the maps 
$f\wedge g:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
f\wedge g(v,w)&=&(f\wedge g-g\wedge f)(v,w)\\
&=&f(v)g(w)-g(v)f(w)\\
&=&
\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}
f(v)& g(v)\\
f(w)& g(w)
\end{array}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
are natural to describe.

Comment: with this being, then it is easy to trace what happens when a base change at the vector space: if $b_i=B^s{}_ie_s$ is one of them and since the new components are related by $B^{-1}=[B^s{}_i^{-1}]$, then is possible to prove that a bilinear $Q:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ in the new basis is given by $B^{\top}QB$